# Is text file or sqlite data manageable when submitted to the AppStore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sqlite

I have an iPhone app that loads data from 100 different text files. I would like to know if I am able to update and manage those text files when they are in the AppStore. Something like that I have a user named John, but I want to change his name. Can I do this when the app is in the AppStore?

Also, is data in sqlite databases manageable when submitted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on where the files are being loaded from. If they're resources built into the app, then no, you can't change anything without resubmitting the app. But you can, of course, change files that your app loads from a server.

A common way to deal with this kind of situation is to include the most up-to-date files you have in your app, but build in the ability to retrieve newer versions from your server. Then, as you make changes and post them on your server, your app will update itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends. You **cannot** change any part of the app bundle when it is on the App Store without resubmitting a new version and having it go through the review process. You can however have your app download files from a server and use those in your app. Then just update the files on your server to be whatever you like.